# Profile not part of artifact name

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3, build-automation

My project uses code that can run on either Android or Java. To abstract out the non-common pieces, we use the same API but platform specific implementations - one for Android and one for Java.

Something like this:

```
common/src/main/java/...
droid/src/main/java/...
POJ/src/main/java/...
```

common can have a dependency on *either* droid.jar or POJ.jar.

I'm using profiles to do an android build (specifying the droid.jar dependency) followed by a java build (specifying the POJ.jar dependency) on common. This causes a clash since both create an artifact with the same name but different content.

Am I asking maven to bend over backwards? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to build two common.jars in one build?

Comment: In a sense, yes. Invoking the build twice is not a problem as long as the artifacts don't clash with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use some plugin to build your jar/war/.... 
In maven profile, you could not only declare dependencies, but also plugin configurations.

it look like:

```
<profile>
  <id>whatever</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <groupId/>
      <artifactId/>
      <version/>
      <configuration>
        ...
      </configuration>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

For example, if you use maven-jar-plugin. you could define the [finalname](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#finalName), to get unique name from different profiles.

however, be careful that if you build with one profile, then if you `mvn -Panother clean package` it will remove the other one.

Another approach is to create sub-module with different dependencies.

Comment: Well, the final name isn't really useful since it doesn't get stored in the repo. The sub-module idea is interesting, but I'd end up creating empty modules referring to the same source code and have to hack the source code location.

Comment: I have yet to try overloading the artifactId in the profile. That's a good idea and maybe the only solution. Thanks!